# SqPayForm is not rendering the fields in ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, square, square-connect

Hi I am working on **ionic 3** and integrating the square connect payment in application I have included the sqpayform [online](https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform) js file in index.html and added the sqpayform script in my ionViewDidLoad function of ionic
I have taken this code from square connect official apis example
 which is following

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
console.log('ionViewDidLoad PaymentAddPage');


this.paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({

  // Initialize the payment form elements
  applicationId: "sandbox-someapp",
  locationId: "someId",
  inputClass: 'sq-input',

  // Customize the CSS for SqPaymentForm iframe elements
  inputStyles: [{
      fontSize: '.9em'
  }],

  // Initialize Apple Pay placeholder ID
  applePay: {
    elementId: 'sq-apple-pay'
  },

  // Initialize Masterpass placeholder ID
  masterpass: {
    elementId: 'sq-masterpass'
  },

  // Initialize the credit card placeholders
  cardNumber: {
    elementId: 'sq-card-number',
    placeholder: '•••• •••• •••• ••••'
  },
  cvv: {
    elementId: 'sq-cvv',
    placeholder: 'CVV'
  },
  expirationDate: {
    elementId: 'sq-expiration-date',
    placeholder: 'MM/YY'
  },
  postalCode: {
    elementId: 'sq-postal-code'
  },

  // SqPaymentForm callback functions
  callbacks: {

    /*
     * callback function: methodsSupported
     * Triggered when: the page is loaded.
     */
    methodsSupported: function (methods) {

      var applePayBtn = document.getElementById('sq-apple-pay');
      var applePayLabel = document.getElementById('sq-apple-pay-label');
      var masterpassBtn = document.getElementById('sq-masterpass');
      var masterpassLabel = document.getElementById('sq-masterpass-label');

      // Only show the button if Apple Pay for Web is enabled
      // Otherwise, display the wallet not enabled message.
      if (methods.applePay === true) {
        applePayBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';
        applePayLabel.style.display = 'none' ;
      }
      // Only show the button if Masterpass is enabled
      // Otherwise, display the wallet not enabled message.
      if (methods.masterpass === true) {
        masterpassBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';
        masterpassLabel.style.display = 'none';
      }
    },

    /*
     * callback function: createPaymentRequest
     * Triggered when: a digital wallet payment button is clicked.
     */
    createPaymentRequest: function () {

      var paymentRequestJson ;
      /* ADD CODE TO SET/CREATE paymentRequestJson */
      return paymentRequestJson ;
    },

    /*
     * callback function: validateShippingContact
     * Triggered when: a shipping address is selected/changed in a digital
     *                 wallet UI that supports address selection.
     */
    validateShippingContact: function (contact) {

      var validationErrorObj ;
      /* ADD CODE TO SET validationErrorObj IF ERRORS ARE FOUND */
      return validationErrorObj ;
    },

    /*
     * callback function: cardNonceResponseReceived
     * Triggered when: SqPaymentForm completes a card nonce request
     */
    cardNonceResponseReceived: function(errors, nonce, cardData, billingContact, shippingContact) {
      if (errors) {
        // Log errors from nonce generation to the Javascript console
        console.log("Encountered errors:");
        errors.forEach(function(error) {
          console.log('  ' + error.message);
        });

        return;
      }

      alert('Nonce received: ' + nonce); /* FOR TESTING ONLY */

      // Assign the nonce value to the hidden form field
      document.getElementById('card-nonce').value = nonce;

      // POST the nonce form to the payment processing page
      document.getElementById('nonce-form').submit();

    },

    /*
     * callback function: unsupportedBrowserDetected
     * Triggered when: the page loads and an unsupported browser is detected
     */
    unsupportedBrowserDetected: function() {
      /* PROVIDE FEEDBACK TO SITE VISITORS */
    },

    /*
     * callback function: inputEventReceived
     * Triggered when: visitors interact with SqPaymentForm iframe elements.
     */
    inputEventReceived: function(inputEvent) {
      switch (inputEvent.eventType) {
        case 'focusClassAdded':
          /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
          break;
        case 'focusClassRemoved':
          /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
          break;
        case 'errorClassAdded':
          /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
          break;
        case 'errorClassRemoved':
          /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
          break;
        case 'cardBrandChanged':
          /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
          break;
        case 'postalCodeChanged':
          /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
          break;
      }
    },

    /*
     * callback function: paymentFormLoaded
     * Triggered when: SqPaymentForm is fully loaded
     */
    paymentFormLoaded: function() {
      /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
    }
  }
});



 }
```

why my form is not rendering the input field  even there is no error on console
Am doing right or is there another way to do this ?

[image]

Here is my html code

```
<div id="sq-ccbox" *ngIf="paymentForm">

       <form id="nonce-form" novalidate action="path/to/payment/processing/page" method="post">
         Pay with a Credit Card
         <table>
         <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td>Card Number:</td>
             <td><div id="sq-card-number"></div></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>CVV:</td>
             <td><div id="sq-cvv"></div></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>Expiration Date: </td>
             <td><div id="sq-expiration-date"></div></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>Postal Code:</td>
             <td><div id="sq-postal-code"></div></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td colspan="2">
               <button id="sq-creditcard" class="button-credit-card" (click)="requestCardNonce($event)">
                 Pay with card
               </button>
             </td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
         </table>

         <input type="hidden" id="card-nonce" name="nonce">
       </form>
     </div>
```

these are missing properties 
[image]

Comment: Just to clarify: are you actually seeing "ionViewDidLoad PaymentAddPage" in the console? Are you including the Square hosted JS file before your own (you didn't show this in your HTML file)? I'm not familiar with Ionic, so just trying to get the basic questions out there.

Comment: Ys its showing console log and im including js file in index.html from offcial url @sjosey

Comment: Is this site live or localhost? The Square Payment form must be hosted on HTTPS which is a common reason it doesn't load.

Comment: There is some missing properties in sqpayform object when I consoled log and compare it with web sqpaytform what could be the reason ? @sjosey

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly - could you update your post with a screenshot of the errors you're referring to?

Comment: when I consoled loged the sqpayForm object it has some missing properties @sjosey

Comment: check my question I edited @sjosey

Comment: I'm having similar issues. I developed using chrome and even there, unpredictably the square payment options will appear and not appear. It often will fix itself if I refresh the screen, but it's causing our customers much grief. It's not only in chrome, but has appeared in firefox, safari and edge as well, so I don't think it's browser related. Has anyone confirmed if it's a timing issue... or order of loading js libraries issue... or other...?